# dell E6500 laptop will not hibernate/standby

Tags: windows-xp, laptop, hibernate, standby

I am using a Dell E6500 laptop with windows XP on it, it was originally tagged/installed with Windows Vista.

My issue is, when I close the lid, it will not either Hibernate or Standby.  If I close the lid with either of these options, I then have to startup from scratch, and anything I had open is not open.  I just want to close the lid, have it keep what I have running, not use power util I open the lid again and start it up (with the stuff still open I had open of course).

Suggestions?

Comment: I assume you have checked the power settings and the setting is not set to shut down? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, looked at and tried all kinds of options, bottom line is it locks up and needs to hard boot when opened back up

Answer (score 1):

Go to the [Dell Support site](http://support.dell.com), enter your service tag and download/install the most recent drivers for your machine for Windows XP. Also be sure and do the same for the Bios.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a problem with the file that windows uses to store the state of the computer before hibernating. It has happened a few times for me where the file becomes corrupt and each time it does a hard restart out of hibernation mode.

If it doesn't go to standby or hibernate when you close the lid, check the power settings. You might not have it configured to enter those modes. If the settings are correct you should check which battery mode you are in. Several laptops give you a high performance or a low performance, high battery life mode. Just click on the battery icon in the taskbar to check this.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is about VGA driver. You can reinstall your laptop's graphic card. If your problem is not resolved, you should go to Dell Support and download the final version of laptop VGA driver. I'm working in windows 7 with this model and it hasn't any problem.